# Windows terminal: How to use context menu?

Tags: powershell, context-menu, windows-terminal

Some users often imply *CMD* or *PowerShell* when they talk about **Windows terminal**. But I have question about the thing that is literally called **Windows terminal**.

With *PowerShell* I can open context menu (with holding shift) in some directory and there will be a button `Open PowerShell here`. So, if I click the button while I in `C:/Users/Me/Desktop`, *PowerShell* will be opened in `C:/Users/Me/Desktop`. The same situation with Linux shell.

But I didn't find any similar functionality in *Windows terminal*. All I want is to make an opportunity to have `Open Windows terminal here`. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible, but you have to fabricate it yourself. To get you started, you can open a Windows Terminal by using the command wt. (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows)

Comment: [Here is a record of how to add PowerShell to the context menu](https://petri.com/add-powershell-windows-explorer-context-menu-windows-10), prior to MS providing that. So, if you really want to try this, you can try the same steps and hook to the file location here: 'C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps'

Comment: Yet, you can save yourself all this headache and just copy the 'Windows Terminal' shortcut to your SendTo folder, then in Explorer, select your file and select Send To, then select Windows Terminal or whatever other thingies you have pinned there.

Comment: WT is a Windows Store App, cmd.exe, powershel.exe, powershell_ise.exe, pwsh.exe are not. Agreed with Austin T French, but it would not make sense for a Windows Store app (UWP containerized) will get such an option. It's not even pinned by default on the Start Menu, unitl you tell it. Well initially it was not. Same goes fro the taskbar pinning. For a long time PowerShell via a context menu was not a thing, they fixed that. Yet, prior to that there, as Austin T French, points out were several articles on how to change the registry to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a Registry key similar to this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\WindowsTerminal\command]
@="C:\\Cascadia\\WindowsTerminal.exe -d ."
```

adjust as needed to point to the path of your executable.

https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/7681

Answer (score 0):

This functionality, isn't really a function of the application, but rather of the registry.

Applications that have this as a feature, are taking advantages of how Windows works.

The 1st step, for many might be reinstalling the application and looking for an option similar to "Enable 'Open Here' in context menu". If it isn't a current build, it will probably be added in the future.

For right now though:

It doesn't appear possible.

Windows Terminal is wt.exe, and calling '/h' against it returns no useful parameters to be  called.

Theoretically, once it supports more parameters you can add a registry key to call a path (Similar to PowerShell and cmd now) to launch `wt.exe /path '%V'` or similar...

Comment: `wt -h   wt --help     or wt /? ` all work

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments:

1. In windows Explorer type:

   shell:SendTo

   It, of course, will open the SendTo folder
2. Create a new shortcut here for the 'Windows Terminal' exe.

> C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe

The actual store shortcut app is in another location. Though it can be copied, it cannot be made visible in SendTo or normal Explorer windows.

3. Change the icon to whatever you want, but the WT icon is not available, so you'd have to create that or use the PSv7 ico, which is virtually the same.
4. Go to a script in Windows Explorer

   Right-Click, select Send To, Select your target app.

As pictured:
[image]

I have many apps that do not appear in the Explorer context menu that I'd like to have there as you can see and do not want to spend all that time mucking with the registry. Sure, it's one extra click, but easy to do, no registry hacking, easy to backup and restore as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just use PowerShell [­OpenHere](https://github.com/KUTlime/PowerShell-Open-Here-Module) module.

#### Disclaimer

I'm developer of this module.